# What went wrong with my code?Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: python, list, adjacency-matrix

So I got this list

```
integer_data=[[2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 6], [1, 3, 6], [0, 1, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

and I got another list of list

```
adjList=[[1, 0], [0, 2, 3, 1], [1, 3, 4, 5, 2], [1, 2, 4, 5, 3], [2, 3, 5, 6, 4], [2, 3, 4, 6, 5], [4, 5, 6]]
```

and an empty list

```
listPrint=[]
```

I want to take the first number in each list of integer_data;e.g. no.2 then find the list in adjList  which last number matches that number(in this case no.2),which is list [1, 3, 4, 5, 2].If there are items in the list in integer_data that is not in [1, 3, 4, 5, 2] then I append 'No' to listPrint, else I append 'Yes'.Then I move on to the next list in integer_data and repeat.

The last number of each list in adjList is unique.The output should be

```
resultList=['Yes','No','No','No','No','No']
```

I tried with this code and the result was quite far off.I'm new to Python so any help will be appreciated.

```
for item in integer_data:
itemToCheck=item[0]
 for itemTwo in adjList:
    itemTwoToCheck=itemTwo[-1]
    if itemToCheck==itemTwoToCheck:
        itemToCompareOne=item
        itemToCompareTwo=itemTwo
        for itemThree in itemToCompareOne:
            if itemThree not in itemToCompareTwo:
                listPrint.append('No')
            else:
                listPrint.append('Yes')
```

Comment: In your example, the length of `integer_data` is `5`, but your `resultList` has length `6`, which doesn't seem right according do your problem description. The length of `resultList` should be the same as the length of `integer_data` right?

Comment: Please come up with a better title for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us work through your example. Based on your description, I assume the expected answer is `['yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'no']`, since there are only `5` lists in `integer_data`.

Also, for brevity, I renamed the two lists to `A` and `B`.

```
A=[[2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 6], [1, 3, 6], [0, 1, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
B=[[1, 0], [0, 2, 3, 1], [1, 3, 4, 5, 2], [1, 2, 4, 5, 3], [2, 3, 5, 6, 4], [2, 3, 4, 6, 5], [4, 5, 6]]
listPrint=[]

# Construct dictionary d. 
# For every list in B, map its last element to the list itself
d={}
for list_b in B:
    d[list_b[-1]] = list_b

'''
In your example, d is
{   0: [1, 0],
    1: [0, 2, 3, 1],
    2: [1, 3, 4, 5, 2],
    3: [1, 2, 4, 5, 3],
    4: [2, 3, 5, 6, 4],
    5: [2, 3, 4, 6, 5],
    6: [4, 5, 6]
}
'''

for list_a in A:
    list_b = d[list_a[0]] # find the corresponding list_b
    answer = 'yes'
    for a in list_a:
        if a not in list_b:
            answer = 'no'
            break
    listPrint.append(answer)

print(listPrint) # ['yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'no']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure algorithmic question independent from programming language.

Below approach may help you make it efficiently:

1. Copy the first element of all lists in integer_data(in the same order). say first_elem_list
2. Copy the last element of all lists in adjList (in the same order). say last_elem_list
3. Now, check what all indices(positions) first_elem_list members have matches (i.e, same value) in last_elem_list
4. If there is a match, then check for the numbers being present as told in the question. If not, straightaway mark "no" in the output list.

Hope this approach breaks down further :)

Answer (score 0):

List Comprehensions are the pythonic way to loop through the items in a list and create a new list from operations on the input list's elements

```
alast = [e[-1] for e in adjList]

['Yes' if (d[0] in alast) and
          set(d).issubset(adjList[alast.index(d[0])])
       else 'No'
 for d in integer_data]

['Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No']
```

the 1st listcomp makes a list of the last number `e[-1]` in each sublist `e` of `adjList`

the second block is actually a single list comprehension (with added line breaks) that takes the sublists `d` from `integer_data` in the last line: `for d in integer_data`

the inline if-else of the 1st 3 lines gives `'Yes'` or `'No'` based on the logic split between the 1st and 2nd lines

the 1st line of logic `(d[0] in alast)` is pretty obvious

the 2nd line of the logical epression "`and`-ed" with the 1st checks if all of the numbers in `d` are in the matched index `alast.index(d[0])` sublist of `adjList` using python's `set` built-in object's `.issubset()` method logic

Comment: If I were to modify this to append no if any of the item ininteger_data is similar to item in the list chosen in adjList.How shd I do this?

Comment: do you mean a new 'similarity' test or just if there is already a 'yes' in the listPrint list? `listPrint += ['no'] if ('yes' in listPrint) else []`